# Why is average so popular when measuring application performance

Tags: performance, statistics, theory

When measuring application performance (response time for example) it's so easy to come across averages (mean). `ab`, `httpref` and bunch of other utilities are reporting mean and standard deviation. But from theoretical point of view it doesn't make a lot of sense to me. And there is why.

Mean value is good at describing symmetrical distributed population, because in case of symmetrical distribution mean is equal to population mode and expected value. But response times are not distributed symmetrical. They are more like exponential. In this case average tells us nothing.

It's more convenient to work with percentile values, which tells us what response time we could afford in what percentage of responses.

Am I missing something or mean is popular just because it's very simple to calculate?

Comment: Are you sure that even though they call it mean, they don't compute the expected value ?

Comment: Because external random influence on performance tends to make the distribution normal, one usually reports the average processing time but only given the _same input set of arguments_. Averaging over requests with different processing time is mostly meaningless. That's why there are standardised benchmarks with fixed inputs.

Comment: @Razvan `ab` standart outputs says: min, mean, [+/-sd], median, max. So I think it's just mean.

Comment: @HristoIliev `httperf` for example can replay session log to a system under test. Session can contains different requests. And still averages are reported.

Comment: @HristoIliev even so response times will never been normally (Gaussian) distributed. The system can't do work faster than it can, only slower. So response time distribution is usually have long tail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All kinds of tools get their features not necessarily from what makes sense, but from users' expectations.

You're absolutely right that the distributions are non-negative and heavily skewed, and that percentiles would be more informative.

Alternatively, a distribution more like lognormal or chi-square would be a little better.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are missing something.

The whole point of descriptive statistics is to present a few numbers to describe (or represent or model or ...) a large number of numbers.  They aid the comprehension of large datasets, the extraction of information from data, the approximate comparison of datasets whose exact comparison is large and bewildering to the limitations of the human mind.

But no single descriptive statistic is always fit for all purposes, and no one is dictating to you that you must or should or ought to use the mean.  If it doesn't suit your purposes, use something else.

As it happens you are quite wrong to write *They are more like exponential. In this case average tells us nothing.*  For an exponential distribution with rate parameter `lambda` the mean is simply `1/lambda` so the mean tells you everything about an exponential distribution.

Comment: I doesn't mean that response times are strictly exponentially distributed. I just mean that usually these distributions have "long tail". They also frequently could be bi- and multimodal. But I get your point about descriptive statistics, thanks. The problem is that in performance analysis no practical outcome could be built upon mean value. But still, mean values are very popular.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in statistics but i believe the average values are used so much because those are the values that help to measure the scalability of a system.

You need to consider first your average values to know how your system needs to bahevae under certains workloads and those needs to be predictable, you usually are not very interested in outliers at least not at first.

Of course you need to look into your min values and the peak values to know the moment your system its going to have a bottleneck but the average values show you as i said a correct and predictable behavior.

Comment: I doesn't understand your point. What does average say us about scalability of the system? I guess throughput is more appropriate measure of the scalability.